# How to backup the PC?

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup

Is there a software to use to backup our computer? I mean with all files and installed components, basically the exact state of my computer right now. How can I make the backup? Or windows have such a functionality?

Comment: Just copy all the bytes on your disk. You might boot a Linux live USB key and use [dd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) but there are zillions of other solutions. In practice, most of the bytes on your disk are not important, and you don't need to backup them. You do need to understand what files and bytes are important to you.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is called an image backup. There are a number of programs which will perform this amazing feat. It requires that you have sufficiently sized media onto which you would store the image, as well as a version of the software with which the image was created. I've found it useful to use the feature of an imaging program to create a rescue drive as well. This allows one to start the computer using the software's OS, which then seeks an image file from which to perform the recovery/restoration.

[A resource](https://www.techradar.com/best/best-backup-software) found by searching for "image backup software" provides a list of five "recommended" programs for 2020, including:

- Acronis True Image
- EaseUS ToDo Backup
- Paragon Backup & Recovery
- NovaBackup
- Genie Timeline

I've used Acronis and found it to be well suited, but recent changes (subscription purchase) makes it less attractive to some users. EaseUS has produced a program of which I am familiar and it also is well suited for this type of operation.

Years ago, Nova was a good product. It's been too long since I've explored it to make a comment for today's use.

The terms "image backup" are ambiguous enough to generate search results relating to backing up graphic images.

Comment: Isn’t this capability built into Windows 10? https://www.windowscentral.com/how-make-full-backup-windows-10?amp

Comment: Yes I prefer if windows can do it rather than using other software

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the programs already mentioned above, you can also refer to this [backup software](https://www.ubackup.com) AOMEI Backupper and [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com).